# Why Satoshi Nakamoto does not want to show up?

Tags: bitcoin-core

The Bitcoin was originally created by Satoshi Nakamoto, and is now becoming a very popular thing. However, I am wondering why the creator of the Bitcoin chose to use a pseudo name as Satoshi Nakamoto, instead of using the real name to make himself or herself famous?

Comment: Since this is a question that only Satoshi can answer himself, I don't think this is will find a reliably answer here. As far as I know, Satoshi neither announced his departure nor gave a reason.

Comment: Satoshi is a SPOF so he hide himself.